# How to remove Source Map error only on remote server

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have developed a website with bootstrap and leaflet on a local computer.  I added the source map files and the compiled css and js files (but not the minified versions).  I am not getting any errors when using developer tools locally.  However, when I FTP the files to the server, which is Unix running Apache, I now get a parse error when opening the developer tools:

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://{file location}leaflet.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This error happens for the leaflet map file and also the map files for bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css.  Note that the leaflet.css file is in the root since it requires its own subfolder for images.  It is not generating an error.

I do realize I can disable the use of map files but I don't want to.  Also, maybe I could just put everything in the website root but I don't want to do that either.  Anybody know what the issue is so I can implement a solution that preserves the file structure and allow me to debug?

Comment: This looks like an error with your compiler, since you are getting an `unexpected token` error. You should look at how your source maps are being generated first.

Comment: If the parse error is a `<` at the first character, chances are that your webserver is returning a 404 error response with some HTML in its body. Do check the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Well the map files come from Bootstrap and Leaflet - I didn't generate them.  So it seems like it must be related to the server environment.  I checked the Network tab in the developer tools.  Nothing is failing to load.  Thanks for thinking about the problem though.  Let me know if you come up with anything else.